# Signature of quadratic form and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I'm asking about the signature of the quadratic form - the triple (n0, n+, n−).
Is it true that n+ is the number of positive eigenvalues, and n- is the number of negative of eigenvalues of the matrix that represent the quadratic form?

Thanks!

Comment: You find the answer here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia      You should really learn to find the answer of such simple answers by googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed n+ is the number of positive eigenvalues, and n- is the number of negative of eigenvalues of the matrix that represent the quadratic form, thanks for the comment that navigated me.